# What is the most polished OSS ticket system?

Tags: email

I am particularly interested in solutions that do very well creating tickets from e-mail, and that allow replies to be sent back and forth via e-mail in a threaded fashion.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think I'm qualified to say which is the *most* polished, I would definitely say Redmine is very competitive in that area.  http://www.redmine.org

We recently began using it in our department and the most frequent comment from the users has been how clean and usable the application is.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think I'm qualified to say which is the *most* polished, I would definitely say [rt](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) is worth looking at.  We've used it in a company of about 40 - 60 people for IT and related issue tracking.  I rate it as extremely easy to use, our sysadmin thought it was easy to install and configure/